# None of the audio devices has speakers associated with them

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

### SYMPTOM

[image: Testing Dialog]

I hear no sound.

In the settings apps, Sound tab, I can select these devices:

**HDMI / Display Port - Built-in Audio**

**Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built-in Audio**

**Headphones - Built-in Audio**

**Dummy Output**

When I click TEST on any of them, there are no speakers I can click. I expect a LEFT and RIGHT button to show up.

### UPDATE 1

When I start pulseaudio from the command line, in verbose mode, it terminates quickly, after a few seconds with:

```
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: We are idle, quitting...
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon shutdown initiated.
```

Starting pulseaudio with a larger idle timeout, give the same result: no audio output, no speakers in the dialog.

### UPDATE 2

When this issue happens, a reboot fixes it temporarily.

I tried to trigger the issue after a reboot with a suspend/wake-up cycle, but after waking up, the sound was still working. So it takes more than a suspend to trigger it.

### SPECS

***OS:*** Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

***Kernel:*** 5.18.12

***Driver:*** snd_hda_intel

***Journal:***

```
$ journalctl -b  | grep -i audio
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops)
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC897: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0x11/0x0
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Front Mic=0x19
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x1a
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: usb 1-11: Product: USB PnP Audio Device
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: hid-generic 0003:0D8C:0134.0008: hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Device [C-Media Electronics Inc. USB PnP Audio Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-11/input2
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
Jul 20 12:33:45 deca dbus-daemon[648]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.35' (uid=1000 pid=886 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo")
Jul 20 12:34:10 deca pulseaudio[886]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Jul 28 16:55:01 deca kernel: [    886]  1000   886   524399     1657   258048      817             0 pulseaudio
Aug 03 16:28:30 deca simplescreenrecorder.desktop[563602]: [ALSAInput::GetSourceList] Found device: [hw:1,0] USB Device 0x46d:0x9a6: USB Audio
Aug 03 16:28:30 deca simplescreenrecorder.desktop[563602]: [ALSAInput::GetSourceList] Found card: [hw:2] USB PnP Audio Device
Aug 03 16:28:30 deca simplescreenrecorder.desktop[563602]: [ALSAInput::GetSourceList] Found device: [hw:2,0] USB PnP Audio Device: USB Audio
Aug 03 16:28:30 deca simplescreenrecorder.desktop[563602]: [PulseAudioInput::GetSourceList] Generating source list ...
Aug 03 16:28:30 deca simplescreenrecorder.desktop[563602]: [SourceNamesCallback] Found source: [alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00.mono-fallback] USB PnP Audio Device Mono
Aug 03 16:28:30 deca simplescreenrecorder.desktop[563602]: [SourceNamesCallback] Found source: [alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo.monitor] Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
Aug 03 16:29:58 deca dbus-daemon[648]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.2989' (uid=126 pid=593603 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo")
Aug 03 16:30:28 deca dbus-daemon[648]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.3031' (uid=126 pid=594175 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo")
Aug 03 16:31:15 deca pulseaudio[886]: X11 I/O error handler called
Aug 03 16:31:15 deca pulseaudio[886]: X11 I/O error exit handler called, preparing to tear down X11 modules
```

**lspci**:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7ad0 (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 87fb
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 150
    Memory at 6003218000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 6003000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: Other than the missing speakers in the test dialog the devices work or not? And is it different if you boot a supported kernel?

Comment: @ChanganAuto There is no sound. And the distro's supported kernels do not support the Alderlake GPU.